# VS2017 Chrome Browser Debugger "Object reference not set to the instance of an object"

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, exception, visual-studio-2017

I am having trouble debugging my web project using the Chrome Browser. I can only use IE to do my debugging. I did some "googling" to resolve this problem, and came across a few Microsoft threads that said to update to the latest version of VS2017, which I did. I use version 15.9.13 and Visual Studio 2017 tells me I am "up to date" when I check for further updates.

When I first updated VS 2017, it started working, and I could debug using Chrome (finally!). But now it has stopped working again.

I saw in other threads where people suggested deleting the .vs folder, which I did, but had no luck with that.

Google Chrome is up to date at Version 75.0.3770.100
I debug and run my application as "Administrator" so that shouldn't be the problem either. I also close all browsers before running the debugger, so Chrome isn't running elsewhere when I try to debug.

Is there any explanation why Chrome cannot launch when using debugger? I would really like to use Chrome because of it's superior "dev tools" and inspection tools. Any suggestions? Was sad to have it working only one day.

Answer (score 1):

Having configured the same environment like yours(VS version and Chrome version) but can't reproduce the issue.I would think if something is broken in VS or maybe third-party extension is the causes this issue.

Please try:

1. [VS repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and a reinstall of Chrome(don't forget to backup the bookmarks)
2. Uninstall or disable third-party vs extensions, this won't take effect until restart vs
3. Navigate to `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.xxx` directory, delete all `ComponentModelCache` folders in all 15.xxx folders.
4. Open your project in vs, changed the target browser `from Chrome to IE`. Then F5 and wait **until it is finish**. Stop it and change the browser `back to Chrome`. After that the error disappeared.
5. Also, create a new `asp.net web app` and debug it with Chrome browser to check if the issue persists. Hope it helps.

Comment: I did remove all the ComponentModelCache folders and entries, and it worked for like half a day. Then it started happening again so I gave up. I also upgraded to VS2019 yesterday and I still get this error. I still cannot debug in Chrome

Comment: @AussieJoe Sorry but I can't reproduce same issue in my machine. Does it make any difference when you check the `Enable Javescript debugging for asp.net` option in Debug menu=>Options and run vs as admin?